# Swift how to choose local database for offline dictionary?

Tags: ios, swift, database, core-data, realm

I want to make an offline translator (dictionary) with swift 4.

I need advice on where to store words with translation. 
The words with the translation are now in the dsl format and I search for this particular file, but on average it takes 2-3 seconds to search.

Is it possible to speed up the search? If i put words with translation in core data or realm database, its help or not ?

Comment: What's the use case for a dsl formatted file? What code are you using to search the file? If your algorithm is mal-formed to the point where it takes 2-3 seconds to locate a match, then there may be an issue with your code; using another platform may or may not be a solution. Can you post your code? What types of queries are you running? How large a file is it? Are you loading the entire file into memory? We would really need to understand the use case - and in general, asking for opinions is outside the scope of this site. If you can clarify your question we may be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Realm Swift enables you to efficiently write your app’s model layer in a safe, persisted and fast way. Here’s what it looks like:

```
// Define your models like regular Swift classes
class Dog: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name = ""
    @objc dynamic var age = 0
}
class Person: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name = ""
    @objc dynamic var picture: Data? = nil // optionals supported
    let dogs = List<Dog>()
}

// Use them like regular Swift objects
let myDog = Dog()
myDog.name = "Rex"
myDog.age = 1
print("name of dog: \(myDog.name)")

// Get the default Realm
let realm = try! Realm()

// Query Realm for all dogs less than 2 years old
let puppies = realm.objects(Dog.self).filter("age < 2")
puppies.count // => 0 because no dogs have been added to the Realm yet

// Persist your data easily
try! realm.write {
    realm.add(myDog)
}

// Queries are updated in realtime
puppies.count // => 1

// Query and update from any thread
DispatchQueue(label: "background").async {
    autoreleasepool {
        let realm = try! Realm()
        let theDog = realm.objects(Dog.self).filter("age == 1").first
        try! realm.write {
            theDog!.age = 3
        }
    }
}
```

For a dictionary app. I'd definitely go with Realm. it uses NSFileProtection and encryption so people won't be able to steal your translation data.

[Setup RealmSwift for your projects](https://realm.io)

Comment: I think the answer is a bit premature. While it's great data, it doesn't appear to be related to the question which is; *will putting data in Realm or CoreData be faster than reading it from a dsl file*. There's nothing in this answer that speaks to performance between the two or the reason Realm would be a better fit. The inital question is pretty broad as well (see my comment) so without more data, it would really be hard to answer. Can you include some comparative information along with the example code so it answers the question?

Comment: This question is opinion based and as a user of realm for years, I have just stated my opinion.

Comment: Heard. I was just hoping you could provide some data points to the original poster comparing performance differences between dsl file access and realm or core data since that's what he was asking about.

Comment: Cool. Thank you for the tip. I’m afk right now. Think I can update the answer in a few hours